# Flash Builder - iPad 3 Resolution

Tags: ios, ipad, apache-flex

So I know I read somewhere when the iPad 3 was released, that you had to build your app using a newer iOS SDK to get the full resolution.

Has anything happened since then?

What would be the easiest way for me to publish apps that use the full resolution of the retina display on the new iPad 3 from Flash Builder?

Thanks,

Comment: I only write native code, but as far as I know, just adding the @2x resources should work, old SDK or not.

Comment: What do you mean? The problem is that the resolution looks like crap when I publish from Flash Builder. It fills the whole screen as it should, but you can easily see that it's not using the retina resolution to display it (looks up-scaled).

Comment: Oh, I see... Then, looks like a limitation offlashBuilder. Sorry I can't help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started: http://www.overdigital.com/2012/05/08/the-new-retina-ipad-and-adobe-air/

Comment: Thanks mate! But what does he mean with "In Flash Builder, it’s even easier – the native extensions dialog features an iOS SDK option to define the path to the desired SDK." ? I can't see any more detailed information about this..

Comment: That means that you have to specifically add the iOS 5.1 SDK to be packaged with AIR. You can add that SDK in the native extensions tab when you make a release build. Air 3.3, upon release, will support the SDK by default, so you won't have to do anything in this regards.

Comment: Is this only for Mac, or also Windows? Forgot to specify that I'm working in Windows.. =/

Comment: I don't have access to a Windows machine, but I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work with Windows.

Comment: Changing the iOS SDK is only supported on Mac; although Adobe has stated it is their long term intention to get this working on Windows too.  Today, you'll have to run Flash Builder 4.6 on OSX to get this working.  ( since you need a Mac to upload to the app store, the general assumption is most devs targeting iOS will have a Mac)

Comment: ahh, ok. Thanks. I'm hoping for a solution soon. Though I'm not sure we will see one yet =/

Thanks for all the help =)

Comment: As I said, with the release of Air 3.3 you should be good to go. Beta 3 is out for a while now so I don't think it'll be much longer till the official release.